# Excel Hlookup Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> Use the HLOOKUP function in cell H9 to calculate the product pricing based on the color and quantity of the billboards ordered. Product pricing can be referenced on the "Product Pricing" lookup table (range O9:Q18). Be sure to use appropriate relative and absolute cell references

**Here is the Excel HyperLink, click over the tabs to "lookup functions", you will find where i'm struggling under cell h9 price.**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7bd7lcs4nzbfwe/logicandreference914.xlsx?dl=0

What I have Which is wrong:

`=HLOOKUP(D9,$O$9:$Q$18,2,TRUE)`

D9 lookup value refers to #shipped

I have no problem with vlookup but i'm struggling to put in the lookup value and row index number in the right spot for hlookup.

Comment: That [HLOOKUP formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-3e471748-33a9-4fbb-b133-fac33f0a4d2a) will return the value in O10:Q10 that corresponds to the approximate match of D9 in O9:Q9. Without sample data and the expected results, that is as close as I can offer.

Comment: How can I attach excel spreadsheets to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Post the workbook to a public file site like Google Drive or DropBox and come back to edit your question and include a link to the publically accessible file.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not signing up for a file service just to download a workbook so I can solve your problems for you. I suggested a *publically accessible file*. The link you provided is not.

Comment: Does dropbox work for you?

Comment: Sure. Just drop it into the *DropBox\Public* folder on your computer and post the link back here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7bd7lcs4nzbfwe/logicandreference914.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: It is under the lookup functions tab, i have four open with four projects i'm working on for school.

Comment: Here is my updated formula. I'm getting closer, just have a mistake or two.   =HLOOKUP(C9,$O$9:$Q$18,4, TRUE)

Comment: Can you update the question with what data is in Columns O, P and Q, and the data in D9?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7bd7lcs4nzbfwe/logicandreference914.xlsx?dl=0   Shauno if you go to the lookup functions tab, you will find all the information you need. Best,

Comment: I'm unable to access dropbox behind my work firewall, thought I'd try and get an idea of the data you're working with. As I imagine the values in O9, P9 and Q9 are a colour/quantity? Then maybe you need a dynamic reference for where you have the 2 in your original formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the formula you are looking to put into H9.

```
=HLOOKUP(C9, $P$9:$Q$18, MATCH(D9, $O$9:$O$18), FALSE)
```

The [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-3e471748-33a9-4fbb-b133-fac33f0a4d2a) provides the column (P ro Q) to retrieve the data from by looking for an *exact match* of the value in C9 against P9:Q9 (the first row in $P$9:$Q$18).

The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) provides which row to retrieve by looking up C9 in O9:O18. This is an approximate match so the values in O9:O18 need to be sorted in ascending order which they are. You want an approximate match because if you have more than 10 (the max in the table), you want it to return the value for 10 and not an error.

So with the row and the column, you are returning the correct value from O9:Q18. Fill down as necessary.

You do have a problem with *# Shipped* being 1. Either you can cover for quantities greater than 10 or less than 2 but not both. Probably better just to add an entry for a quantity of 1.

[image: HLOOKUP with MATCH]

You will want to familiarize yourself with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to provide error control.

With your lookup table in O9:O18, with the *# Shipped* starting at *2*, you could also shortcut this to,

```
=HLOOKUP(C9, $P$9:$Q$18, D9, FALSE)
```

But that not does cover quantities greater than 10 *or* a quantity of *1* so it is a bit of a step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wound up with
=HLOOKUP(C9,$O$9:$Q$18,D9,TRUE)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider adding to your answer some explanation as to how/why your code addresses the OP's question.